# Pass select value to controller without refreshing the page (AJAX, RAILS, JS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm a newbie using AJAX and now I'm trying to work on a group of select boxes so that when the user selects a value from the first, the second updates its values. I'm trying to use AJAX, JQuery and ROR, but so far, I can't fetch the value from the first box and pass it to the controller in order to filter the results of the second.

This is my code for index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, remote: true, :method => 'get', class: "forma") do %>

   <%= select_tag("box", options_from_collection_for_select(@posts, :content,     :content), :prompt => "Select") %>

       <p>

   <%= select_tag("nbox", options_from_collection_for_select(@listposts, :content,         :id), :prompt => "Select") %>

   <p>

   <%= submit_tag "Show", class: "btn btn-info" %>

    <% end %>
```

This is my index.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".btn").on("click", function() {
           $('.table').fadeToggle();
   })

   $('#box').change(function(){
          $.ajax({ 
             type: 'POST', 
             url: '/jess/rails/dummy/app/controllers/posts_controller', 
             data: {'filter' : $(this).val() }, 
             success: function(data){
             } 
          })
          $('#nbox').fadeIn();
      $('.btn').fadeIn();
   })
})
```

This is my controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash.now[:notice] = "YEAH"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @post.content}
        format.js
      end
    else
      render "/"
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @listposts = Post.where('content LIKE ?', params[:box])
  end

  def next
     @listposts = Post.where('content LIKE ?', params[:box])
   end

  private

    def post_params
        params.fetch(:post, {}).permit(:content)
    end

end
```

I think I'm doing it wrong with the AJAX part in the js.erb but I've changed it so many times I don't know anymore. Your help would be so very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple of small problems.

First, it looks like the URL you are using may be wrong. The URL for the AJAX request would be the same format as the URL if you were to view that page in your browser.

With what you provided I can't tell exactly what it should be, but I can give you an example. Assuming you access your index page by just "http://example.com/index" (or something similar),  you would also call the function you want as something based on it's route. If the route was "update", then it would be something like "http://example.com/update".

Basically, don't use the folder path but use the web path instead.

Second, you don't do anything your success callback in your AJAX request. With AJAX, you send and receive info from the server, then you have to use JavaScript to update whatever you need updated manually. So, you'll need to have your update action return some information which you can then use to change the state of your second set of boxes.